# Using Arial with pdflatex wanted

Tags: fonts

I do not want to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, can I use the Arial font anyway?

According to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23957/how-to-set-font-to-arial-throughout-the-entire-document) the Arial font can be used when using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. When I use XeLaTeX I get new problems like my copyright signs are not recognized. What can I do?

Comment: This is just a duplicate of the linked question. The answers there don't require XeTeX/LuaTeX unless you pick the bits that say, 'If XeTeX/LuaTeX, then ...'. 95% of the material there has nothing to do with XeTeX/LuaTeX. You can't use an arbitrary font with a traditional engine without installing it which means creating the required `.tfm`, `.fd`, `.map` etc. files. (And you can only do that if the font is in a suitable format or you can convert it to one.)

Comment: @cfr helvet is not arial, and uarial is imho not very good (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309120/2388). On windows I would suggest to try the winfonts package. But the best would be to sort out the xelatex problems instead of trying to find a bad workaround.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree. Helvetica is much nicer ;). (Not sure about `uarial` as I'd never choose Arial given a choice anyway.) Perhaps you should add an answer to the other question suggesting `winfonts`? (Assuming that the current version of Windows provides a truetype Arial sufficiently similar to whatever XP provided.) Sorting out the issues with XeTeX (or using LuaTeX which I find often works when XeTeX doesn't) would definitely be the most straightforward solution, albeit a different question.