# How to use URW-Arial font in pdflatex for both text and Mathematics

Tags: fonts, mathematics

I want to use urw-arial fonts for mathemtical text also. For text, I can do something like

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

from one of the answers given in stackexchange.
How do I do it for mathematics text? For example, is it possible to get  the x in $x^2$  in the italics  version of urw-arial? What commands should I use?

**Update** I created a style file and used it.  The following are the contents of the style file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{myarial}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{uarial}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}     {T1}{fav} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}  {bold}{T1}{fav} {b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`a}
\DeclareMathSymbol{b}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`b}
\DeclareMathSymbol{c}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`c}
\DeclareMathSymbol{d}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`d}
\DeclareMathSymbol{e}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`e}
\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`f}
\DeclareMathSymbol{g}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`g}
\DeclareMathSymbol{h}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`h}
\DeclareMathSymbol{i}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`i}
\DeclareMathSymbol{j}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`j}
\DeclareMathSymbol{k}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`k}
\DeclareMathSymbol{l}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`l}
\DeclareMathSymbol{m}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{n}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{o}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`o}
\DeclareMathSymbol{p}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`p}
\DeclareMathSymbol{q}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{r}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`r}
\DeclareMathSymbol{s}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`s}
\DeclareMathSymbol{t}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`t}
\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`u}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`v}
\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`w}
\DeclareMathSymbol{x}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`x}
\DeclareMathSymbol{y}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{z}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{A}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{B}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{C}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{D}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{E}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{F}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{G}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`G}
\DeclareMathSymbol{H}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`H}
\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{J}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`J}
\DeclareMathSymbol{K}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{L}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`L}
\DeclareMathSymbol{M}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{N}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{O}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{P}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Q}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`Q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{R}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`R}
\DeclareMathSymbol{S}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`S}
\DeclareMathSymbol{T}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{U}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`U}
\DeclareMathSymbol{V}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`V}
\DeclareMathSymbol{W}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`W}
\DeclareMathSymbol{X}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Y}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{Z}{\mathalpha}{letters}{`Z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{operators}{`9}
\endinput
```

At first glance, everything looks OK.  But, in mathematics mode, I am 
getting semi-colon instead of comma everywhere. Also, the output for \inf and \sup commands are not in URW-Arial. I am using stix fonts for mathematics. Can this be a reason? How to fix these problems?

Comment: There are packages for that, note however that none of those are perfect and might give you ugly results. See for example `mathastext`

Comment: Two other packages, which might help (I don't know for sure): `sansmathfonts` or `sansmath`.

Comment: I wouldn't use uarial: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309120/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. I earlier tried to use Xelatex. But that didn't work. I have posted a question with MWE in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400438/how-to-use-urw-arial-font-in-pdflatex-for-both-text-and-mathematics-in-xetex