# How to install Arial in TeX Live 2019 in Windows 8.1 (64 Bit)

Tags: fonts, texlive, installing, texmaker, windows

I hope someone has the kindness and endurance to help me out with installing `uarial` in TeX Live, I would be really grateful for that.
I have tried so much for a few days now and for me it is quite complicated because I am not used to this stuff - but unfortunately I have to specifically use Arial in my thesis, so here I am.

I have downloaded `uarial` from [getnonfreefonts](https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) and have run in `cmd.exe  texlua install-getnonfreefonts` (as administrator). I get this, which looks fine to me?:

> C:\Users\~\Desktop> texlua install-getnonfreefonts Detected System:
>   win32 Detected Installation: C:/texlive/2019 Installing
>   texmf-dist/scripts/getnonfreefonts/getnonfreefonts.pl ...     [done]
>   Installing texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts.1 ...
>   [done] Installing texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/getnonfreefonts.man1.pdf ...
>   [done] md5sum: a9e772165e8fdb620bcf9c75c17facda getnonfreefonts.pl ...
>   [ok] md5sum: 49be4444054d85b6037d237552a7cea1 getnonfreefonts.1 ...
>   [ok] md5sum: f825d523d686dbecdc787535b40f09d0 getnonfreefonts.man1.pdf
>   ...      [ok] Creating wrapper in 'bin/win32' ...
>   1  Datei(en) kopiert.   [done] mktexlsr: Updating
>   C:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/ls-R... mktexlsr: Updated
>   C:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/ls-R. mktexlsr: Done.

After this I used `getnonfreefonts --sys -all`, and I end up with this:

> C:\Users\~\Desktop>getnonfreefonts --sys -all
>   --2019-05-07 22:22:03--  https://www.tug.org/~kotucha/getnonfreefonts/getfont.p
>
> Resolving www.tug.org... 91.121.174.77 Connecting to
>   www.tug.org|91.121.174.77|:443... connected. HTTP request sent,
>   awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 33001 (32K) Saving to:
>   'getfont.pl'
>
> getfont.pl          100%[===================>]  32,23K  --.-KB/s    in
>   0,03s
>
> 2019-05-07 22:22:03 (1,04 MB/s) - 'getfont.pl' saved [33001/33001]
>
> ---------------------------------------------- Installation directory: C:/texlive/texmf-local
>   ---------------------------------------------- arial-urw      Arial (URW)                                          [installed] classico
>   Classico (URW)                                       [installed]
>   dayroman       Day Roman (Apostrophiclabs)
>   [installed] gandhi         Gandhi (Librerias Gandhi S.A. de C.V.)
>   [installed] garamond       GaramondNo8 (URW)
>   [installed] garamondx      GaramondNo8 Expert (URW & Michael Sharpe)
>   [installed] lettergothic   LetterGothic (URW)
>   [installed] literaturnaya  Literatunaya (Paragraph)
>   [installed] luximono       Luxi Mono (Bigelow & Holmes)
>   [installed] vntex-nonfree  VnTeX nonfree (URW & Han The Thanh)
>   [installed] webomints      Webomints (Galapagos Design Group)
>   [installed]

To be sure I ran `getnonfreefonts --sys --refreshmap`, too:

> C:\Users\~\Desktop>getnonfreefonts --sys --refreshmap
>   --2019-05-07 22:27:05--  https://www.tug.org/~kotucha/getnonfreefonts/getfont.p
>
> Resolving www.tug.org... 91.121.174.77 Connecting to
>   www.tug.org|91.121.174.77|:443... connected. HTTP request sent,
>   awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 33001 (32K) Saving to:
>   'getfont.pl'
>
> getfont.pl          100%[===================>]  32,23K  --.-KB/s    in
>   0,02s
>
> 2019-05-07 22:27:06 (1,41 MB/s) - 'getfont.pl' saved [33001/33001]
>
> ---------------------------------------------- Installation directory: C:/texlive/texmf-local
>   ---------------------------------------------- Installing 'ua1.map'...                                                  [done] Installing 'classico.map'...
>   [done] Installing 'dayroman.map'...
>   [done] Installing 'gandhi.map'...
>   [done] Installing 'ugm.map'...
>   [done] Installing 'zgm.map'...
>   [done] Installing 'ulg.map'...
>   [done] Installing 'tli.map'...
>   [done] Installing 'ul9.map'...
>   [done] Installing 'garamondvn.map'...
>   [done] Installing 'classicovn.map'...
>   [done] Installing 'webo.map'...
>   [done]
>
> Running 'mktexlsr C:/texlive/texmf-local >NUL 2>NUL' ...
>   [done]
>
> Updating map files (updmap-sys). Be patient...
>   [done]

When I checked in C:\texlive\2019\texmf-config\web2c the `updmap.cfg` file I found this:

> Map ua1.map Map classico.map Map dayroman.map Map gandhi.map Map
>   ugm.map Map zgm.map Map ulg.map Map tli.map Map ul9.map Map
>   garamondvn.map Map classicovn.map Map webo.map

After this I went to Texmaker and included:

```
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

and I get this :(

> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults
>   substituted. LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/ua1/m/n' undefined
>   LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape`T1/ua1/m/sc' undefined

The produced pdf is written in Helvetica or some other kind, at least it is not Arial...

When I just include

```
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

there is no error message, but the font isn't changed to Arial either.

Can someone please help me? Thank you SO much in advance!
Best regards.

Comment: uarial is a curious mix between helvetica and arial: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309120/2388. Beside this the font substituation messages looks harmless.

Comment: `OMS/ua1/m/n` would be for math symbols. `T1/ua1/m/sc` would be upright small caps.

Comment: New Arial (win10) NOT= Old Arial (XP) = an older MSwin font ~= modified Helvetica ~= Uarial  *therefore* Uarial NOT= Arial   So what do you realy need? Nearest for pdfLaTeX may be modified winfont loading Arial from Win8.1 (?Old/New Arial?) otherwise easy route use XeLaTeX

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks for pointing out that uarial is not the exact same thing as Arial and the link!

Comment: Thanks everyone! This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you posted should work.  URW Arial is not exactly the same as the version from Monotype that Microsoft distributes.

The messages you got are mostly harmless.  `OMS/ua1/m/n` is a math symbol alphabet.  `T1/ua1/m/sc` is small caps.

If you’re allowed to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, and you want to use Microsoft Arial, the best approach is:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Arial}[Scale = 1.0]
```

If you want to use Arial in math mode as well, [see here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469775/how-to-use-math-mode-and-siunitx-with-arial)

In PDFLaTeX, you can also use `winfonts`.  (As of 2018, this was broken on systems that have a newer version of the fonts installed, including Windows 10.)

```
\usepackage{winfonts}

\fontfamily{arial}\selectfont
```

You can also `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{arial}` All the `winfonts` package itself does is change the encoding to T1, but including it will at least tell anyone trying to compile your document what package they need to install.

Another option is to use the original font on which Arial was based, Helvetica.  Win points with typography snobs!  TeX Gyre Heros is a very similar Helvetica clone.  There is also Arimo.

Comment: imho the winfonts package no longer work with newer windows versions as glyph names in the fonts have changed, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339253/2388.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, okay. I think installing the older version of the fonts in a directory that your engine would search first would be a stopgap, but we can hope there’ll be an update to `winfonts`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added a comment. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Thank you (all) so much for the explanations! Using XeLaTeX and and you code I get a pdf which is in Windows Arial and I am very happy about that :-)
At least the pdf, which I find in the folder, is. 
**This leads to my next question:**
When I compile the document with XeLaTeX in Texmaker and click on "View PDF" the pdf is shown with an updated text, but the shown font is Helvetica and not Arial. But as I said, the produced PDF in the folder is in Arial. Can I somehow adjust texmaker so that both the produced PDF and the Viewer show Arial?

Comment: @TeXlearner I’m not sure what the issue is there, sorry. You might have some extra packages in your preamble. If you load `fontspec`, don’t also use `fontenc`, `inputenc`, `uarial`, `winfotns`, etc.

Comment: You can [change the PDF viewer that TeXMaker uses.](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION02) Also make sure it knows you’re compiling with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Davislor I checked the preamble and this isn't the issue, but nonetheless thanks for that, I wasn't aware of that! Also I viewd your link but couldn't find the soultion... I will close this question and open a new one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490001/188437

Comment: Big thanks to everyone for helping so far! :)