# Arial appearing incorrectly in the built-in PDF viewer in Texmaker

Tags: xetex, pdf, texmaker

I am using XeLaTeX with TeX Live 2019 in Windows 8.1 (64 Bit).

Arial appears incorrectly in the built-in PDF viewer - when I compile the document with XeLaTeX in Texmaker and click on "View PDF" the pdf is shown with an updated text, but the shown font is (probably) Helvetica and not Arial. But as I said, the produced PDF in the tex folder is in proper Arial. Moreover the font in the pdf view is slightly thicker than it actually is in the pdf. Can I somehow adjust texmaker so that both the produced PDF and the Viewer show the correct Arial?

This is my tex document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec} \defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase} \setmainfont{Arial}[Scale = 0.95]
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,paper=a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document} 

\section{Chapter auioe}
This is an example.

Pipe sign: |   Less than: <   Greater than: >

\end{document}
```

[image]
(left Adobe, right Texmaker)

I compile with XeLaTeX + view pdf and so far I haven't changed anything else...

Comment: Looks like Arial to me, the G is quite characteristic. See e.g. https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/03/arial-vs-helvetica-can-you-spot-the-difference/

Comment: The difference is in the font rendering. Try printing both, they'd look the same.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! Now I can see it, too :)

Comment: @OlegLobachev Thank you for the keyword, now I can search a bit more about rendering :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendering of fonts within internal and external viewers is down to different rendering engines, their settings and their interaction with the operating system (Look closely at the way my Acrobat/Windows is **pixelating the TTF for screen**). However the only proof is the listing of the subset fonts shown by Acrobat and here we see both confirmed as Arial.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I see that my problem is just the rendering in my Texmaker, not the used font itself. Is there a possibilty to adjust something, maybe in Texmaker, so that the pixelation isn't that bad?

Comment: It is down to lots of conflicts & preferences , I would say the Acrobat pixilation as "wrong" and the Texmaker as right since  Anti-aliasing is the smoothing of jagged screen edges. I dont like Acrobat to use anti-aliasing because it covers up subpixel rendering issues. So I keep it set for screen use. Win10 drivers do all they can to "enhance" ClearType font handling. Scaling screen resolution will thwart that. So generally I don't bother tweaking the system since what's good for one app on this pc will surely be wrong for 50% of others. I would raise tweaking question with texmaker support

Comment: I see the point - good idea, I will do that! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 3):

It is the Arial. Print the list of fonts of the pdf:

```
bash-3.2$ pdffonts document.pdf
name                     type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
JCVHJM+Arial-BoldMT      CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      4  0
VCAPFA+ArialMT           CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this possibility to check the used font - thanks a lot!